# Find smallest set of rows whose column sums at least reach a target

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math, subset-sum

I'm trying to write an algorithm that prints the solution for the following problem:

> Given a target array T = [t<sub>1</sub>, t<sub>2</sub>, ...
> t<sub>n</sub>], and a set of lists S = { A = [a<sub>1</sub>,
> a<sub>2</sub>, ... a<sub>n</sub>], B = [b<sub>1</sub>, b<sub>2</sub>,
> ... b<sub>n</sub>], ... X = [x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ...
> x<sub>n</sub>] }, what is the subset of S with the lowest cardinality
> that satisfies the condition where the sum of the i<sup>th</sup> terms
> of each array in the subset are at least t<sub>i</sub>?

Example:

```
T = [2, 3, 1]

S = {[0, 1, 2], [1, 0, 1], [2, 2, 0]}
```

The subset with the lowest cardinality that satisfies the above conditions is the set `{[0, 1, 2], [2, 2, 0]}`. Expressing the sums of each array's i<sup>th</sup> terms as `[2, 3, 2]`, you can see that each i<sup>th</sup> sum is greater than or equal to the i<sup>th</sup> term of T.

I've looked at other subset-sum problems but can't come up with an efficient algorithm to solve this one.

Comment: What did you try so far? Do you have a working solution but it's not "efficient" enough, or do you have some issues with your solution?